# Impala via JDBC admitting queries sequentially from threads in same Java Process

Tags: cloudera, impala

I am using Impala JDBC driver 2.5.32 on Cloudera 5.8.1. I run my Java code which spawns 10 different threads. Each thread instantiates it's own java.sql.Connection from DriverManager and makes one "insert into taget_table select field1,field2...fieldN, count(*) from source table group by field1,field2...fieldN" query. The query is big enough to run for a few minutes. Each query has a peak memory usage

I see that, even though, the threads have executed the query and waiting for the response, On the Imapala side I see that only one query is being executed at a time.

However, instead of threads, if I run them as different Java processes, The queries are run in Parallel. Could someone throw some light on why this could happen? Please let me know any additional details that I can provide..